# Why S3method dispatch gets slower? S3 dispatch vs manual do.call benchmark

Tags: r, performance, benchmarking

Any idea why S3 dispatch gets slower than manual do.call for large inputs?

```
library(rbenchmark)
foo1 <- function(x)UseMethod("foo1",x)
foo1.integer <- function(x)x+1
foo2 <- function(x)do.call(paste("foo2",class(x),sep="."),list(x))
foo2.integer <- function(x)x+1`
```

small input

```
>benchmark(sapply(1:1e3L,foo1))
              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 sapply(1:1000, foo1)          100    0.92        1      0.86        0         NA        NA
>benchmark(sapply(1:1e3L,foo2))
              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 sapply(1:1000, foo2)          100    1.12        1      1.09        0         NA        NA
```

but then

```
benchmark(sapply(1:1e4L,foo1))
               test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 sapply(1:10000, foo1)          100   29.48        1      27.2     0.03         NA        NA
> benchmark(sapply(1:1e4L,foo2))
               test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 sapply(1:10000, foo2)          100   12.39        1     11.75     0.03         NA        NA
```

EDIT

```
> benchmark(foo1 = sapply(1:10000, foo1), foo2 = sapply(1:10000, foo2), replications = 1000)[1:4]
  test replications elapsed relative
 1 foo1         1000  302.00    2.412
 2 foo2         1000  125.21    1.000
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure you are really timing the dispatch since there is a lot more going on with the `sapply`.  Try this:

```
> library(rbenchmark)
>
> foo1 <- function(x)UseMethod("foo1",x)
> foo1.integer <- function(x)x+1
>
> foo2 <- function(x)do.call(paste("foo2",class(x),sep="."),list(x))
> foo2.integer <- function(x)x+1
>
> benchmark(foo1 = foo1(1L), foo2 = foo2(1L), replications = 100000)[1:4]
  test replications elapsed relative
1 foo1       100000    2.81    1.000
2 foo2       100000    3.48    1.238
```

Note that when I tried the `sapply` comparison `foo1` was still faster:

```
> benchmark(foo1 = sapply(1:100, foo1), foo2 = sapply(1:100, foo2), replications = 1000)[1:4]
  test replications elapsed relative
1 foo1         1000    2.31    1.000
2 foo2         1000    2.80    1.212
```

Comment: OK! Plain (at top level) S3 dispatch is faster, but the vectorized is not!?

Comment: Have added additional info to answer.

Comment: It seems a matter related to size of the vector, because for the vector 1:10000 foo1 is not the faster, at least in my computer!

Comment: Maybe that is the reason why getSymbols set in **quantmod** is implemented with do.call!?